# Excel File is not Opening when returned as InputStreamResource

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, file

I am trying to create an API which is sending InputStreamResource of an excel file. which is created at server side from the data of a table.

when i hit this api from postman the excel file is not opening and says it doesn't have right extension or file is corrupted.

I have saved the file at the server side which is opening fine.

have tried to send HTTP ENTITY as well.  still got same response

It is my controller

```
@GetMapping(path = RestMappingConstants.AdminRequestUri.DOWNLOAD_A2TO_INTERVIEWER_EXCEL)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadA2ToInterviewPaymentExcel( ) throws IOException{
    ByteArrayInputStream in = a2AdminService.downloadA2ToInterviewPaymentExcel();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //InputStream res=A2AdminController.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("payment.xlsx");
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PaymentDetails.xlsx");
    headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .body(new InputStreamResource(in));
}
```

It is my service class

```
@Override
public ByteArrayInputStream downloadA2ToInterviewPaymentExcel() throws IOException {
    List<A2ToInterviewerPaymentEntity> a2ToInterviewerPaymentEntityList = a2AdminDao.getApprovedPaymentList();
    // FileOutputStream file=new FileOutputStream("payment.xlsx");
    // convert to excel
    String[] columns = { "Id", "Amount", "PaymentMode", "PaymentType", "TransactionId", "InterviewScheduleId",
            "EmployerToPaymentEntityId", "PaymentStatus" };
    try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("payment");
        Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
        headerFont.setBold(true);
        headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
        CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
        // Row for Header
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
        // Header
        for (int col = 0; col < columns.length; col++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(col);
            cell.setCellValue(columns[col]);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        }
        int rowIdx = 1;
        for (A2ToInterviewerPaymentEntity paymentEntity : a2ToInterviewerPaymentEntityList) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIdx++);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(paymentEntity.getId());
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(paymentEntity.getAmount());
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue("UPI");
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue("TRANSFER");
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(paymentEntity.getTransactionId());
            row.createCell(5).setCellValue(paymentEntity.getInterviewSchedule().getId());
            row.createCell(6).setCellValue(paymentEntity.getEmployerToA2PaymentEntity().getId());
            row.createCell(7).setCellValue(paymentEntity.getPaymentStatus().toString());
        }
        workbook.write(out);
        // workbook.write(file);
        byte[] arr = out.toByteArray();out.flush();out.close();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(arr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file downloaded from postman is input array stream. you need to handle this stream in frontend code to convert in to corresponding file. To do it frontend angular code is as below

```
var result = this.budgetService.downloadEstimates(this.userDetail.userId);
          result.subscribe(
            data => {
              this.utilitiesService.hideLoader();
              const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
              if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'results.xlsx');
              }else{
              //let blob = data;
              let a = document.createElement("a");
              a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              a.download = 'results.xlsx';
              document.body.appendChild(a);
              a.click();
            }
          },
            error => {
              this.utilitiesService.showInformation('Download has failed', 'Error');

            })
        }
        downloadResultSubscriber.unsubscribe();
      });
```

To download file directly from controller use below piece of code but this should be reverted as soon as frontend api starts integrating the apis.

```
@GetMapping(path = /download)
    public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException{
        File  f =  // your file here;
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        httpServletResponse.setContentLength(f.length);
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PaymentDetails.xlsx");
        FileCopyUtils.copy(f, httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
        httpServletResponse.flushBuffer();
    }
```

Comment: what i need to do so that user just click the button and file get downloaded

Comment: How would i test that my api is working fine and the excel file generated is currect?

Comment: You will definitely need a frontend code to test your api, but to test the excel file you can make a simple java class and verify the file contents

Comment: Another option to test the api from postman is to modify the controller to download the file directly instead of returning responseEntity. In this case you can test you api but will have to modify the code before frontend starts integrating it.

Comment: how would i directly download the file from the controller

Comment: Please refer my updated answer on how to directly download the file

Comment: can you let me know if this solution worked, it is always preferred to reply so that we all know heading direction

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion but the solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code in your controller:

```
ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" +yourFileName".xlsx")
            .body(yourFileInByteArray);
```

Comment: This isn't going to help as downloading a file is different from sending it as response entity

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this is not helping me out

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. It was problem of the postman.When i tried to hit the same API with the browser by surpassing the security it worked fine.

I think postman was creating the issue with the downloaded excel file